# How can I route all VMWare Player traffic through a SOCKS proxy on the host?

Tags: networking, proxy, vmware

I want to route *all* Internet traffic from a VMWare guest, through a socks proxy that runs on the host. Seems like a common enough thing to want to do, but apparently it's been impossible to do, at least in [2007](https://communities.vmware.com/message/689266#689266) or [2009](https://communities.vmware.com/message/1157388#1157388).

How can that be done?

My host is Ubuntu and I tried `proxychains4 vmplayer` with the NAT setting for the guest, but traffic went through my host's IP.